# The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present in datatable nopcommerce 3.80

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken, nopcommerce-3.80

I want to fetch data and show in datatable in nopcommerce 3.80. When I am doing at that time it shows the error i.e. **The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.** I add **antiforgery** keyword also whenever want to put like controller and in view form, still shows the same error.

Here is my form view,

```
<form id="Master-form" name="Master-form">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="content">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <div id="product-edit" class="nav-tabs-custom">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    @Html.RenderBootstrapTabHeader("tab-country", @T("Admin.Master.Country"), true)
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    @Html.RenderBootstrapTabContent("tab-country", @TabCountry(), true)                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my partial view

```
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                @T("Admin.Master.CountryList")
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="dataGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Country Name</th>
                            <th>Active</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dataGrid').DataTable({
            "scrollX": true,  // scrolling horizontal
            "bSort": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "pageLength": 5,
            "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 50, 100, 1000, 10000],

            "ajax": {
                "url": 'AwazMaster/CountryList',
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },

            "columnDefs":
                [{
                    "targets": [0],
                    "visible": false,
                    "searchable": true,
                    "orderable": false
                }
                ],
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Id", "name": "Id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "CountryName", "name": "service", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "IsActive", "name": "active", "autoWidth": true },

                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) { return "<a class='btn btn-info' onclick=Edit('" + row.Id + "');   >Edit</a>"; }
                },
                {
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        return "<a href='#' class='btn btn-danger' onclick=DeleteData('" + row.Id + "'); >Delete</a>";
                    }
                },
            ]
        });
    });    
</script>
```

Here is my controller,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult CountryList()
{
    // Getting all data  
    var dataList = _MasterService.CountryList(
        start: Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["start"]),
        pageSize: Request.Form["length"].ToString() != null ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["length"].ToString()) : 0,
        sortColumnName: Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[0][column]"] + "][name]"],
        sortColumnDirection: Request.Form["order[0][dir]"]);

    var data = dataList.Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        CountryName = x.CountryName,
        IsActive = x.IsActive,
    });

    //Returning Json Data
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return Json(new { draw = Request.Form["draw"], recordsFiltered = dataList.TotalCount, recordsTotal = dataList.TotalCount, data = data });
}
```

For more clear above image shows the full error
[image]

while in browser console shows the **500(internal server error)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The required anti-forgery form field “\_\_RequestVerificationToken” is not present in ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773645/the-required-anti-forgery-form-field-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `__RequestVerificationToken` generated inside in your `form` with your ajax request as follows:

```
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

"ajax": {
    "url": 'AwazMaster/CountryList',
    "type": "POST",
    "headers": {__RequestVerificationToken : token} // <--- here it is
    "datatype": "json",
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.