# The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present when using Ajax and Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Controller which have two action methods. Both of them are annotated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]` and `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is included in corresponding view. Now call to one of these methods (`GetVendorOrders`: Whose results are bound to kendo grid) is successful and the other one (`MakeVendorPayment`) throws an exception `"The required anti-forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present" even when both are provided with __RequestVerificationToken value.`

I tried with the following 3 ways:

1. Passing token in headers parameter of AJAX, like:
   `headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': token }`
2. Passing token in data parameter of AJAX, like:
   `data: JSON.stringify({ vendorId: vId, orderIds: oIds, __RequestVerificationToken: token })`
3. Appending token value and passing it to AJAX, 
   `data.__RequestVerificationToken = token;`

--Following are those Action Methods:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public virtual ActionResult GetVendorOrders(DataSourceRequest command, VendorPaymentSearchModel model)
{
    var orders = _orderService.SearchOrders(vendorId: model.VendorId, createdFromUtc: model.StartDate, createdToUtc: model.EndDate);

    var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
    {
        Data = orders.Select(x =>
        {
            return new OrderModel
            {
                CustomOrderNumber = x.CustomOrderNumber,
                CustomerFullName = x.CustomerFullName,
                CustomerEmail = x.CustomerEmail,
                OrderTotal = x.OrderTotal,
                Commission = x.Commission,
                VendorPayment = x.OrderTotal - x.Commission
            };
        }),
    };

    return Json(gridModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public virtual ActionResult MakeVendorPayment(int vendorId, string[] orderIds)
{
    foreach (var orderId in orderIds)
    {
        var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(Convert.ToInt32(orderId));

        var vendorPayment = new VendorPayment()
        {
            VendorId = vendorId,
            OrderId = Convert.ToInt32(orderId),
            OrderTotal = order.OrderTotal,
            Commission = order.Commission,
            Payment = order.OrderTotal - order.Commission
        };

        _vendorPaymentService.InsertVendorPayment(vendorPayment);
    }

    return Json(new { Result = true });
}




`//Following are Javascript functions:
//This Call Successful
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#orders-grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetVendorOrders", "Vendor"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: additionalData
                    }
                },
            },
            dataBound: onDataBound,
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "Id",
                    field: "Id",
                    width: 50
                },
                {
                    field: "CustomOrderNumber",
                    title: "Order #",
                    width: 80
                },
                {
                    field: "OrderStatus",
                    title: "Order Status",
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    field: "OrderTotal",
                    title: "Order Total",
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    field: "Commission",
                    title: "Commission",
                    width: 100
                },
                {
                    field: "VendorPayment",
                    title: "VendorPayment",
                    width: 100
                }
            ]
        });`



    //This results into error: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
    //Commented parts are the other ways that are tried.

    $('#vendor-payment').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var orderIds = [];
        var data = $("#orders-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            orderIds.push(data[i].CustomOrderNumber);
        }

        //var token = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("MakeVendorPayment", "Vendor")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            //cache: false,
            //headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': token },
            //data: addAntiForgeryToken({ vendorId: vId, orderIds: oIds }),
                        data: JSON.stringify({ vendorId: vId, orderIds: oIds, __RequestVerificationToken: token })
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                var grid = $("#orders-grid").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.read();
            },
            error: function (objAjaxRequest, strError) {
                var respText = objAjaxRequest.responseText;
                console.log(respText);
            }
        });
    });


    function addAntiForgeryToken(data) {
        if (!data) {
            data = {};
        }

        var token = $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
        if (token.length) {
            data.__RequestVerificationToken = token.val();
        }
        return data;
    };
});
```

I am surprised that the function where grid is bound (which calls GetVendorOrders), is successful but the button click (which calls MakeVendorPayment) throws error: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after doing some more research, I got the solution.
I just needed to remove **`contentType`** option in the AJAX call, so it uses the default **`'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`** and also removed **JSON.stringify()**.

Changed AJAX call is as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("MakeVendorPayment", "Vendor")',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { vendorId: vId, orderIds: oIds, __RequestVerificationToken: token },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        var grid = $("#orders-grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.read();
    },
    error: function (objAjaxRequest, strError) {
        var respText = objAjaxRequest.responseText;
        console.log(respText);
    }
});
```

Reference: [The required anti-forgery form field “__RequestVerificationToken” is not present in ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45773645/the-required-anti-forgery-form-field-requestverificationtoken-is-not-present)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using kendo you can also make use of the shorthand [kendo.antiForgeryTokens()](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/antiforgerytokens) that does some of the heavy lifting for you, e.g.

```
postData('@Url.Action("MakeVendorPayment", "Vendor")', { vendorId: vId, orderIds: oIds });
...
postData: (url, data) => {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $.extend(data, kendo.antiForgeryTokens())
    }).done(() => {
        viewModel.items.read();
    }).fail((e) => {
        error_handler(e);
    });
}
```